# RAW Printer tunnel

Tags: delphi, printing

I have just coded the windows service which accepts print streams sent from the clients' applications, edits them and sends further to the configured printer.

This all function on RAW mode.
Is it possible for the service to return somehow error code/message to the client?

I know that the client in raw mode printer driver just open the port, send unknown number of bytes and then closes socket. But does it try to read from the server ..?

Thanks!